# SelectTokens with not exists

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to find if there's a nice way using SelectTokens and JsonPath to find all controls with type="check" and no "options". So an example JSON could be:

```
Value = @"{
    ""subsections"": [
        {
        ""name"": ""Subsection Name"",
        ""caption"": ""Subsection Caption""
        },
    ],
    ""controls"": [
       { ""type"" : ""check"", 
           ""name"" : ""Checkbox2"",
           ""caption"" : ""Checkbox Caption 2"",
           ""options"" : [
               { ""caption"" : ""Yes"" },
               { ""caption"" : ""No"" }
           ]
       },
       { ""type"" : ""check"", 
           ""name"" : ""Checkbox2"",
           ""caption"" : ""Checkbox Caption 2"",
       }
    ]
}"
```

I'm trying things like: `$..controls[?(@.type=='check' && !(@.options))]` but I can't see any option to test for a not exists.

The only option that I can think of is getting all `check` types and then using Linq to filter those without options. Just wondering if there is a way to do it solely through JsonPath?

Kind regards
Sidharth

Comment: I don't think Json.NET has this capability.  The set of possible JsonPath operators is given by the internal `QueryOperator` enum in the file [QueryExpression.cs](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L9).  Unfortunately, neither a `Not` operator nor a `DoesNotExist` operator can be found.